# Short javascript version

Tags: google-apps-script, shortcode

I am creating a submit button script where in the data from the first sheet will be transferred to another sheet. Is there a way to shorten the code below? It's too lengthy and I think part of the data was missing when it was transferred. I think it was the E55,H55 and I55

```
function submitentry() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sinput = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  var soutput = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var input = sinput.getRange('C5:C20').getValues();
  var secInput = sinput.getRange('K5:K19').getValues();
  var trdInput = sinput.getRange('B24').getValues();
  var frtInput = sinput.getRange('C24').getValues();
  var fifInput = sinput.getRange('E24').getValues();
  var sxtInput = sinput.getRange('H24').getValues();
  var sevInput = sinput.getRange('B28').getValues();
  var egtInput = sinput.getRange('C28').getValues();
  var ninInput = sinput.getRange('E28').getValues();
  var tenInput = sinput.getRange('H28').getValues();
  var elvInput = sinput.getRange('B32').getValues();
  var twvInput = sinput.getRange('C32').getValues();
  var trnInput = sinput.getRange('E32').getValues();
  var frnInput = sinput.getRange('H32').getValues();
  var fifInput = sinput.getRange('C36').getValues();
  var sxnInput = sinput.getRange('E37').getValues();
  var svtInput = sinput.getRange('H37').getValues();
  var ethInput = sinput.getRange('I37').getValues();
  var nntInput = sinput.getRange('J37').getValues();
  var twyInput = sinput.getRange('C41:C42').getValues();
  var tfiInput = sinput.getRange('E42').getValues();
  var tseInput = sinput.getRange('H42').getValues();
  var tthInput = sinput.getRange('I42').getValues();
  var tfoInput = sinput.getRange('J42').getValues();
  var tfvInput = sinput.getRange('E46').getValues();
  var tsxInput = sinput.getRange('H46').getValues();
  var tseInput = sinput.getRange('I46').getValues();
  var teiInput = sinput.getRange('E47').getValues();
  var tniInput = sinput.getRange('H47').getValues();
  var thyInput = sinput.getRange('I47').getValues();  
  var troInput = sinput.getRange('E48').getValues();
  var trwInput = sinput.getRange('H48').getValues();
  var trtInput = sinput.getRange('I48').getValues();
  var trfInput = sinput.getRange('E49').getValues();
  var trvInput = sinput.getRange('H49').getValues();
  var trxInput = sinput.getRange('I49').getValues();
  var trsInput = sinput.getRange('E50').getValues();
  var treInput = sinput.getRange('H50').getValues();
  var thnInput = sinput.getRange('I50').getValues();
  var ftyInput = sinput.getRange('E51').getValues();
  var fonInput = sinput.getRange('H51').getValues();
  var ftwInput = sinput.getRange('I51').getValues();
  var fthInput = sinput.getRange('E52').getValues();
  var ffoInput = sinput.getRange('H52').getValues();
  var ffiInput = sinput.getRange('I52').getValues();
  var fsiInput = sinput.getRange('E53').getValues();
  var fseInput = sinput.getRange('H53').getValues();
  var feiInput = sinput.getRange('I53').getValues();
  var fniInput = sinput.getRange('E54').getValues();
  var ffyInput = sinput.getRange('H54').getValues();
  var fioInput = sinput.getRange('I54').getValues();
  var fiwInput = sinput.getRange('E55').getValues();
  var fhrInput = sinput.getRange('H55').getValues();
  var ffrInput = sinput.getRange('I55').getValues();
  var fiwInput = sinput.getRange('E56').getValues();
  var fhrInput = sinput.getRange('H56').getValues();
  var ffrInput = sinput.getRange('I56').getValues();
  var ffvInput = sinput.getRange('E57').getValues();
  var fsxInput = sinput.getRange('H57').getValues();
  var fsvInput = sinput.getRange('I57').getValues();
  var fegInput = sinput.getRange('E58').getValues();
  var fnnInput = sinput.getRange('I58').getValues();
  var sxyInput = sinput.getRange('E59').getValues();
  var sxoInput = sinput.getRange('I59').getValues();
  var swoInput = sinput.getRange('E60').getValues();
  var strInput = sinput.getRange('I60').getValues();
  var sfoInput = sinput.getRange('E61').getValues();
  var sfiInput = sinput.getRange('I61').getValues();
  var ssxInput = sinput.getRange('E62').getValues();
  var sseInput = sinput.getRange('I62').getValues();
  var seiInput = sinput.getRange('E63').getValues();
  var sniInput = sinput.getRange('I63').getValues();
  var svyInput = sinput.getRange('E64').getValues();
  var svoInput = sinput.getRange('I64').getValues();
  var svwInput = sinput.getRange('E65').getValues();
  var svhInput = sinput.getRange('I65').getValues();
  var svfInput = sinput.getRange('E66').getValues();
  var svvInput = sinput.getRange('I66').getValues();
  var svxInput = sinput.getRange('E67').getValues();
  var svsInput = sinput.getRange('I67').getValues();
  var sveInput = sinput.getRange('E68').getValues();
  var svnInput = sinput.getRange('I68').getValues();
  var etyInput = sinput.getRange('E69').getValues();
  var eonInput = sinput.getRange('I69').getValues();
  var etwInput = sinput.getRange('E70').getValues();
  var etrInput = sinput.getRange('I70').getValues();
  var efoInput = sinput.getRange('E73').getValues();
  var efiInput = sinput.getRange('H73').getValues();
  var esiInput = sinput.getRange('C77:C80').getValues();
  var eseInput = sinput.getRange('I6').getValues();
  var eeiInput = sinput.getRange('I8').getValues();
  var eniInput = sinput.getRange('I10').getValues();
  var ntyInput = sinput.getRange('I12').getValues();
  var nnoInput = sinput.getRange('I14').getValues();  
  var flatin = [].concat.apply([], input);
  var secFlatin = [].concat.apply([],secInput);
  var trdFlatin = [].concat.apply([],trdInput);
  var frtFlatin = [].concat.apply([],frtInput);
  var fifFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fifInput);
  var sxtFlatin = [].concat.apply([],sxtInput);
  var sevFlatin = [].concat.apply([],sevInput);
  var egtFlatin = [].concat.apply([],egtInput);
  var ninFlatin = [].concat.apply([],ninInput);
  var tenFlatin = [].concat.apply([],tenInput);
  var elvFlatin = [].concat.apply([],elvInput);
  var twvFlatin = [].concat.apply([],twvInput);
  var trnFlatin = [].concat.apply([],trnInput);
  var frnFlatin = [].concat.apply([],frnInput);
  var fifFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fifInput);
  var sxnFlatin = [].concat.apply([],sxnInput);
  var svtFlatin = [].concat.apply([],svtInput);
  var ethFlatin = [].concat.apply([],ethInput);
  var nntFlatin = [].concat.apply([],nntInput);
  var twyFlatin = [].concat.apply([],twyInput);
  var tfiFlatin = [].concat.apply([],tfiInput);
  var tseFlatin = [].concat.apply([],tseInput);
  var tthFlatin = [].concat.apply([],tthInput);
  var tfoFlatin = [].concat.apply([],tfoInput);
  var tfvFlatin = [].concat.apply([],tfvInput);
  var tsxFlatin = [].concat.apply([],tsxInput);
  var tseFlatin = [].concat.apply([],tseInput);
  var teiFlatin = [].concat.apply([],teiInput);
  var tniFlatin = [].concat.apply([],tniInput);
  var thyFlatin = [].concat.apply([],thyInput);
  var troFlatin = [].concat.apply([],troInput);
  var trwFlatin = [].concat.apply([],trwInput);
  var trtFlatin = [].concat.apply([],trtInput);
  var trfFlatin = [].concat.apply([],trfInput);
  var trvFlatin = [].concat.apply([],trvInput);
  var trxFlatin = [].concat.apply([],trxInput);
  var trsFlatin = [].concat.apply([],trsInput);
  var treFlatin = [].concat.apply([],treInput);
  var thnFlatin = [].concat.apply([],thnInput);
  var ftyFlatin = [].concat.apply([],ftyInput);
  var fonFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fonInput);
  var ftwFlatin = [].concat.apply([],ftwInput);
  var fthFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fthInput);
  var ffoFlatin = [].concat.apply([],ffoInput);
  var ffiFlatin = [].concat.apply([],ffiInput);
  var fsiFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fsiInput);
  var fseFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fseInput);
  var feiFlatin = [].concat.apply([],feiInput);
  var fniFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fniInput);
  var ffyFlatin = [].concat.apply([],ffyInput);
  var fioFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fioInput);
  var fiwFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fiwInput);
  var fhrFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fhrInput);
  var ffrFlatin = [].concat.apply([],ffrInput);
  var ffvFlatin = [].concat.apply([],ffvInput);
  var fsxFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fsxInput);
  var fsvFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fsvInput);
  var fegFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fegInput);
  var fnnFlatin = [].concat.apply([],fnnInput);
  var sxyFlatin = [].concat.apply([],sxyInput);
  var sxoFlatin = [].concat.apply([],sxoInput);
  var swoFlatin = [].concat.apply([],swoInput);
  var strFlatin = [].concat.apply([],strInput);
  var sfoFlatin = [].concat.apply([],sfoInput);
  var sfiFlatin = [].concat.apply([],sfiInput);
  var ssxFlatin = [].concat.apply([],ssxInput);
  var sseFlatin = [].concat.apply([],sseInput);
  var seiFlatin = [].concat.apply([],seiInput);
  var sniFlatin = [].concat.apply([],sniInput);
  var svyFlatin = [].concat.apply([],svyInput);
  var svoFlatin = [].concat.apply([],svoInput);
  var svwFlatin = [].concat.apply([],svwInput);
  var svhFlatin = [].concat.apply([],svhInput);
  var svfFlatin = [].concat.apply([],svfInput);
  var svvFlatin = [].concat.apply([],svvInput);
  var svxFlatin = [].concat.apply([],svxInput);
  var svsFlatin = [].concat.apply([],svsInput);
  var sveFlatin = [].concat.apply([],sveInput);
  var svnFlatin = [].concat.apply([],svnInput);
  var etyFlatin = [].concat.apply([],etyInput);
  var eonFlatin = [].concat.apply([],eonInput);
  var etwFlatin = [].concat.apply([],etwInput);
  var etrFlatin = [].concat.apply([],etrInput);
  var efoFlatin = [].concat.apply([],efoInput);
  var efiFlatin = [].concat.apply([],efiInput);
  var esiFlatin = [].concat.apply([],esiInput);
  var eseFlatin = [].concat.apply([],eseInput);
  var eeiFlatin = [].concat.apply([],eeiInput);
  var eniFlatin = [].concat.apply([],eniInput);
  var ntyFlatin = [].concat.apply([],ntyInput);
  var nnoFlatin = [].concat.apply([],nnoInput);
  var lastRow = soutput.getLastRow()+1;
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 1,1,16).setValues([flatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 17, 1, 15).setValues([secFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 32, 1, 1).setValues([trdFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 33, 1, 1).setValues([frtFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 34, 1, 1).setValues([fifFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 35, 1, 1).setValues([sxtFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 36, 1, 1).setValues([sevFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 37, 1, 1).setValues([egtFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 38, 1, 1).setValues([ninFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 39, 1, 1).setValues([tenFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 40, 1, 1).setValues([elvFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 41, 1, 1).setValues([twvFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 42, 1, 1).setValues([trnFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 43, 1, 1).setValues([frnFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 44, 1, 1).setValues([fifFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 45, 1, 1).setValues([sxnFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 46, 1, 1).setValues([svtFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 47, 1, 1).setValues([ethFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 48, 1, 1).setValues([nntFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 49, 1, 2).setValues([twyFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 51, 1, 1).setValues([tfiFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 52, 1, 1).setValues([tseFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 53, 1, 1).setValues([tthFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 54, 1, 1).setValues([tfoFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 55, 1, 1).setValues([tfvFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 56, 1, 1).setValues([tsxFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 57, 1, 1).setValues([tseFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 58, 1, 1).setValues([teiFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 59, 1, 1).setValues([tniFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 60, 1, 1).setValues([thyFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 61, 1, 1).setValues([troFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 62, 1, 1).setValues([trwFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 63, 1, 1).setValues([trtFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 64, 1, 1).setValues([trfFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 65, 1, 1).setValues([trvFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 66, 1, 1).setValues([trxFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 67, 1, 1).setValues([trsFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 68, 1, 1).setValues([treFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 69, 1, 1).setValues([thnFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 70, 1, 1).setValues([ftyFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 71, 1, 1).setValues([fonFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 72, 1, 1).setValues([ftwFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 73, 1, 1).setValues([fthFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 74, 1, 1).setValues([ffoFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 75, 1, 1).setValues([ffiFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 76, 1, 1).setValues([fsiFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 77, 1, 1).setValues([fseFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 78, 1, 1).setValues([feiFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 79, 1, 1).setValues([fniFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 80, 1, 1).setValues([ffyFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 81, 1, 1).setValues([fioFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 82, 1, 1).setValues([fiwFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 83, 1, 1).setValues([fhrFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 84, 1, 1).setValues([ffrFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 85, 1, 1).setValues([ffvFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 86, 1, 1).setValues([fsxFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 87, 1, 1).setValues([fsvFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 88, 1, 1).setValues([fegFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 89, 1, 1).setValues([fnnFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 90, 1, 1).setValues([sxyFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 91, 1, 1).setValues([sxoFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 92, 1, 1).setValues([swoFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 93, 1, 1).setValues([strFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 94, 1, 1).setValues([sfoFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 95, 1, 1).setValues([sfiFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 96, 1, 1).setValues([ssxFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 97, 1, 1).setValues([sseFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 98, 1, 1).setValues([seiFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 99, 1, 1).setValues([sniFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 100, 1, 1).setValues([svyFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 101, 1, 1).setValues([svoFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 102, 1, 1).setValues([svwFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 103, 1, 1).setValues([svhFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 104, 1, 1).setValues([svfFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 105, 1, 1).setValues([svvFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 106, 1, 1).setValues([svxFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 107, 1, 1).setValues([svsFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 108, 1, 1).setValues([sveFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 109, 1, 1).setValues([svnFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 110, 1, 1).setValues([etyFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 111, 1, 1).setValues([eonFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 112, 1, 1).setValues([etwFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 113, 1, 1).setValues([etrFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 114, 1, 1).setValues([efoFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 115, 1, 1).setValues([efiFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 116, 1, 4).setValues([esiFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 120, 1, 1).setValues([eseFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 121, 1, 1).setValues([eeiFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 122, 1, 1).setValues([eniFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 123, 1, 1).setValues([ntyFlatin]);
  soutput.getRange(lastRow, 124, 1, 1).setValues([nnoFlatin]);
  soutput.insertRowAfter(soutput.getLastRow());
  Logger.log(input);  
}
```

I even had to put a lot of texts on this question just to have this submitted. That's how long the code is. So Im not sure if it's reading the data accurately.

Comment: You have some duplicate declarations `var fiwInput = sinput.getRange('E55').getValues();   
var fhrInput = sinput.getRange('H55').getValues();   
var ffrInput = sinput.getRange('I55').getValues();   
var fiwInput = sinput.getRange('E56').getValues();   
var fhrInput = sinput.getRange('H56').getValues();   
var ffrInput = sinput.getRange('I56').getValues();` Also many of your getValues() methods could be a getValue() which doesn't require flattening.

Comment: Yep i also saw it. sorry wasn't able to edit my post :p

Answer (score 2):

You should be loading all these values into an array where the values index in the array is equal to the crazy numbering system you've got going on in the variable names. Those variable names really lend themselves to lots of issues with the way you've abbreviated numbers in strange ways and used those in the variable names. You should definitely package all that in an array or another similar data type, but if you were going to use variables for each one like this it would be better to name them input1, input2, input3, etc instead of input, secInput, TrdInput. No one but you will know those abreviations, and even you will probably forget them and have to look up how they are spelled. You could have also used semantic names that describe what the input is for, or include the range like inputK5K19 or something. Never include uncommon (or worse, just made up) abbreviation as a signifier in your code. It is a much better practice to be clear than to be concise when it comes to naming, and in this case you could have been both more concise and more clear. As I said though, for this, you probably are going to want to package all that in an array rather than have a different variable for each input value. Especially given that this is a spreadsheet you are pulling from, use a datatype to store it that reflects that.

You didn't include enough information for me to rewrite your whole snippet competently, but I would definitely start with storing that input information differently. Once it is stored in an array that will allow you to iterate over it and express a lot of this code within a much more syntactically concise loop.

As I said, some of this may be wrong because I don't know the meaning behind all the number literals you have included in your code but this is my quick attempt to shorten it.

```
function submitEntry() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      ssInput = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form"),
      ssOutput = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard"),
      inputArr = [],
      rangeArr = [
        'C5:C20',
        'K5:K19',
        'B24',
        'C24',
        'E24',
        'H24',
        'B28',
        // ...
        // ... Continue the ranges used in the order you
        // wrote them initially in your parameters for your
        // successive getRange() calls
      ],
      rangeArrLen = rangeArr.length,
      flattenedArrs = [],
      i = 0,
      lastRow = ssOutput.getLastRow() + 1,
      inputArrLen,
      flattenedArrsLen,
      // One of your parameters starts at 32 and then increments all the way to 126. 
      incrementor = 32; 

  for (; i < rangeArrLen; ++i) {
    inputArr.push(ssInput.getRange(rangeArr[i]).getValues());
  }

  for (i = 0, inputArrLen = inputArr.length; i < inputArrLen; ++i) {
    flattenedArrs.push([].concat.apply([], inputArr[i]))
  }

  // Did these two outside the loop because the parameters for getRange
  // didn't match up or sequentially increment the way the others did
  ssOutput.getRange(lastRow, 1,1,16).setValues([flattenedArrs[0]]);
  ssOutput.getRange(lastRow, 17, 1, 15).setValues([flattenedArrs[1]]);

  for (i = 2, flattenedArrsLen = flattenedArrs.length; i < flattenedArrsLen; ++i) {
    ssOutput.getRange(lastRow, incrementor, 1, 1).setValues([flattenedArs[i]]);

    incrementor += 1;
  }

  ssOutput.insertRowAfter(ssOutput.getLastRow());
  Logger.log(input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, appreciate it :) I am not well adept in javascript and this is really helpful. So haven't really tried other means that what I was told to do by someone else :p